# dpkg remove, dependencies problems

Tags: 12.04, apt, 64-bit, dpkg, 32-bit

I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04. I was sure I was installing the 32 bits version, however it turns out (wt* ???) it is actually a 64 bits version. In the meantime, I tried to install some library in its 32 bits version. It didn't work, somehow I ended up with `sudo apt-get -f install` going crazy and wanting to delete everything. I stopped there with the 32 bits library. Then I realized I was running a 64 bits OS, so I downloaded the 64 bits version of the lib. Before running the installation script, I ran the 32 bits lib's remove script, with the following result :

```
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching updatorgui
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching flycapture-doc
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching flycap
...etc.
```

Which makes sense, since I never managed to install the 32 bits lib. So one may think that I could now install the 64. Uh oh :

```
Installing FlyCapture2 packages...
dpkg: error processing libflycapture-2.5.3.4_amd64.deb (--install):
libflycapture2: 2.5.3.4 (Multi-Arch: no) is not co-installable with
libflycapture2:i386 2.5.3.4 (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed
```

So, my questions are :

- How do I clean up dpkg, or remove the 32 bits stuff, and then install my lib ?
- How do I fix apt-get so it doesn't want to delete the whole system ?
- How is this possible that I installed Ubuntu 64 when I'm sure I downloaded the 32 torrent ?

I really tried to make things right, but I'm quite stuck now...

Answer (score 0):

It says it can't install when you have libflycapture2:i386 installed... so remove that package.

```
sudo dpkg -r libflycapture2:i386
```

Comment: the lib remove script performs, among others, sudo dpkg -r libflycapture2:i386, which gives the result I gave in my question (warning, no installed package matching...)

Comment: @CTZStef, what you posted says nothing about being unable to remove libflycapture2.